# Hibernate List returns same object reference for same values in table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

- A has a many-to-one relationship with B.
- B is a kind of type/category table.

I am storing all B primary keys in A table. when I query list of A like the following

```
   SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("select * from A");
   query.addEntity(A.class);
   List list  = query.list();

   A.hbm.xml
   <many-to-one
        class="B" 
        fetch="select" name="b" lazy="no-proxy">
        <column name="b_ID" />
    </many-to-one>
```

This list has same object references of B for same primary keys. A has 4 records out of which 2 records have same B value. I have same object reference of B here though they are 2 different records of A. I need to get different object reference of B here.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: that's just how Hibernate works, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143832/hibernate-cache-level-1 . no way to change it.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to get the different object reference of B. Here I need to modify the B values in A table by getting the list. when I do that, It is modifying all the values that have same primary key of B.